# Can't select Firebase AB Testing Activation event nor Goal metric event

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-ab-testing

When creating Firebase AB experiment our custom events don't show up on the Activation event list nor on the Goal metric event list. Both of those events are properly showing on the Analytics Event dashboard. To make things weirder, at different points in time there was a possibility to select one of them but they were never shown at the same time. Anyone experiencing something similar?

Comment: Is there a chance any of your events use unusual characters? I know there was an issue where events containing extended character sets weren't being carried over into A/B testing. This might be one of those cases,

Comment: @ToddKerpelman thanks for the info, but it seems this isn't the case. Our goal event is called `RegistrationEntryExperimentOneDay` and our activation event `RegistrationEntryExperimentActivationV2`.

Comment: It might not be just the two events you're interested in, but any event that you've used so far. I would take a look at all of your events and just double check that there aren't any unusual characters in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was fixed somehow and now the events are being shown. We didn't do anything from our side so I am hoping someone from the firebase team has intervened and that the issue won't resurface in the next experiment. Thanks!

Comment: The events does not selectable until a few hours that were sent to firebase. You just have to wait.

Comment: Within several hours I would say

Answer (score -1):

Firebase ABT will show events which have been logged in the last 30 days. Please check if the event you want has been logged by your app recently.

Comment: Events were sent in the last 7 day